# Excel: How to join cells in different format?

Tags: excel

Excel: How to join cells in different format?
I need

```
A1 = Text
B1 = 1,1
C1 = A1 & " " & B1
```

I need result: Text 1,10
i need two decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`=A1 & " " & TEXT(B1,"0,00")`

or

`=A1 & " " & TEXT(B1,"0.00")`

If using . instead of , for decimal point